# Proof isomorphism groups.

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a group, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are subgroups of $G$. $L_1$ and $L_2$ are normal subgroups  of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively. If $G_1L_2=L_1G_2$ and $G_1 \cap L_2 = L_1 \cap G_2$ , Prove that $G_1/L_1$ is isomorphic to $G_2/L_2$.

I think that I should use the second Isomorphism Theorem

$$H/(H\cap N)\simeq HN/N$$

But $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not normal in G, right? Some tip to prove that?

My Browser cant add coments , dont work, so in the answer "ϕ:G1→G2/L2,ϕ(g1):=g2L2,when

g1=l1g2", someone could clear this ϕ? ϕ should map g1 in g2 ϕ: g1->g2L2, and Kerϕ should be L1 ?

Comment: Isomorphism $H/(H\cap N)\rightarrow HN/N$ has to look $h+H\cap N=h+N$. Now try to show that it works.

Comment: Hi: welcome to math.SE. Consider using $\LaTeX$ for your typesetting! It is easy to pick up. BIS HD has added these changes for you already: it looks much nicer. Click the timestamp on his/her edit to see how it was done.

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$\phi: G_1\to G_2/L_2\;,\;\;\phi(g_1):=g_2L_2\;,\;\;\text{when}$$

$$g_1=l_1g_2\;,\;\;\text{which follows from}\;\;G_1L_2=L_1G_2$$

Now

$$l_1g_2=l_1'g_2'\implies l_1'^{-1}l_1=g_2'g_2^{-1}\in G_2\cap L_1=L_2\cap G_1\le L_2\implies$$

$$\implies g_2L_2=g_2'L_2$$

and this shows $\;\phi\;$ is well defined. Show now that it also is a group homomorphism, and check that $\;\ker\phi=L_1\;$

Comment: I could write this manner: $$\phi: g_1 -> g_2L_2$$

How do I use this information> $$G_1 \cap L_2 = L_1 \cap G_2$$?

Comment: Why ker$\phi$ is L1?

Comment: Suppose $\;x=l_1g_2\in G_1\;,\;l_1\in L_1\;,\;g_2\in G_2\;\;,\;\;x\in\ker\phi$ , then

$$\phi(x):=g_2L_2=L_2\iff g_2\in L_2\implies $$

$$x=l_1g_2\in G_1\cap(L_1L_2)\stackrel{\text{Dedekind's Modular Law!}}=L_1(G_1\cap L_2)=L_1(G_2\cap L_1)\le L_1$$

and we get that $\;\ker\phi\le L_1\;$ . Now you try the other direction.